# ModelBuilder - Data dependencies within model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, error-000732, validation

I have a "parent" model with two nested submodels.  Submodel A creates a gdb & FC's.  These FC's are output and exposed as model parameters to the input of Submodel B which exports them to CAD.  When I validate the parent model, submodel B does not validate.  I'm guessing this is because its input has not yet been created from Submodel A?  When I run the parent model, I get error 000732 that the input features do not exist.  I'm guessing this error is caused by the same reason.  How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track.  You can set [preconditions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w0000007r000000) in Arc Model Builder to control the order in which parts of the model run.  You can either set them by right-clicking the tool and selecting Precondition from the pop-up menu or by using the connect tool (see [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w00000067000000)).  You can also use Booleans and Positive integers to act as preconditions (possibly set by some other event).

Comment: MappaGnosis, thanks for the response.  I have tried setting the output of submodel A as a precondition to submodel B, however, the model still does not validate.

Comment: Sometimes models which have a dependency on a temporary intermediary file fail to validate (because the file dose not exist) but can still be run.  Do you get the same error when you run the model with the precondition set?

Comment: Yes, I've tried running with preconditions and removing the "intermediate data" check from the output of submodel A.  When I validate the parent model, submodel A validates but submodel B does not.  FWIW, i do get a "model execution may overwrite an output dataset" warning but I don't think its related to the validating.  This warning is because I create a blank feature class and then overwrite/populate the feature class at a later step.