# Submodels in ArcMap work independently, but when linked in a single model I get error 000732

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, error-000732

This has started happening across a couple models I've made. I'll have a basic submodel that links to a buildings layer for an entire country (for example), then clips and buffers and saves it with predesignated names in a predesignated geodatabase.

[image: Constraints_buildings submodel to clip and buffer a house layer and save in a predesignated place. This submodel works without issue.]

That works fine. However, when I group several similar submodels together and link use their outputs to as inputs for the erase tool I get error 000732 (Dataset  does not exist or is not supported). The model will run all of the submodels and save the features in the correct places with the correct names, but it won't run the final erase tool. I can run the erase tool by itself after the model has failed with the features the model created, but it won't do it in the model.

[image: A simplified version of the model that does not work. The real model just has more submodels that do the same clip and buffer as the submodel shown.]

I made each feature a precondition for the erase tool like suggested in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86910/modelbuilder-data-dependencies-within-model) but no luck. When I validate the model I get the following warnings saying that there is a duplicate dataset name. I don't know if this is related, but maybe it's getting confused as to which name to use for the erase tool. Otherwise, how can it the erase tool not recognize where the created in the ModelBuilder tool are if they are linked directly to the tool?

[image: When I validate the model I get these warnings that I'm making duplicate names. Not sure if it's related to the problem though.]

Answer (score 1):

Your screen shot shows that what you are calling the erase tool is not the erase tool but a python script tool called RES_Erase. No one has any idea what's going on in there.

The buffer tool outputs a Feature Class, thats is what the [syntax section](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm#GUID-42A39A8F-CFDB-4B34-88CB-4596EB832658) of the help file is telling you.

Maybe the input of your script tool is expecting a Feature Layer? We don't know as you don't show the parameters of that tool.

Thats is where I would start looking.

Comment: Gotcha, yea my company only has a basic license so we don't have the ESRI Erase tool and just made our own. I'll ask around for what that tool is looking for exactly. Thanks